# Is it possible to use two keyboards with two different keymaps?

Tags: keyboard, keymap, launchpad

Basically, what I am wanting to do is use a keyboard (i.e. in this case my Razer Black Widow as my main keyboard functioning as a keyboard with whatever my default keymap is at the time) and use my other keyboard (i.e. Razer Anansi as a soundboard/launchpad basically remap or extend the keymap).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this little Application found here with instruction , i hope its what you want.

[Using multiple keyboards with different layouts on the same machine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20994/Using-multiple-keyboards-with-different-layouts-on)

Comment: That seems close but instead of switching languages I think what I need is something that either automatically changes keymaps based on the keyboard im typing on or extends the keymap from 101 - 104 to 202 - 208 keys with a modifier key enabled.  I think and example would be on keyboard 1 The A key would be A but on Keyboard 2 the A key would be CTRL+A